# Count results with condition in the select part of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the amount of words that start from all the characters of the alphabet, exist in my database

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(id) FROM(SELECT id FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'A%') as A,
    COUNT(id) FROM(SELECT id FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'B%') AS B,
    ...
    COUNT(id) FROM(SELECT id FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'Z%') AS Z
```

When I run the query, it gives me this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'COUNT'.    
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

The funny thing is that the query works fine if I only ask for the words that start with 'A'

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify for future readers. The reason I want one check per letter of the alphabet, is because the alphabet can be different according to the language of the user and is going to be provided each time the query is generated

Comment: If you want "starts with" shouldn't you put `LIKE 'A%'` NOT `'%A'`

Comment: Talk about unefficient

Comment: Do any of the individual statements work?  In other words, just one of the counts.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: @Loupax Based on this comment `I have to make all those checks, because the alphabet is going to be different`, you seriously need to consider a different approach. Think it this way: If the alphabet is going to change, then you will have to change the CODE of the SQL statement if you go for a `CASE`. If you group them and filter them using a regular expression, as I proposed in my solution below, then the CODE of the SQL statement will remain the same and you only have to change the PARAMETER, which happens to be VERY flexible as it is a regular expression :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE CASE WHEN AS FOLLOWS

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN word LIKE 'A%' THEN 1 END) AS A
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN word LIKE 'B%' THEN 1 END) AS B
.........
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN word LIKE 'Z%' THEN 1 END) AS Z
FROM WORDS
```

Comment: For some reason I think this is more efficient, but thats just a feeling. How does this query work?

Comment: @Loupax This is efficient than a sub-query model you specified in the answer since only one query is executed. Based on the comment you posted later your requirements are getting clearer. If you would post the the input and the output you expect, I can give you a great answer

Comment: What I have is a sequence of letters that can be in any language. What I want, is to feed that sequence of letters to a function that will build an SQL query which will return me a result with the number of words that begin with each letter. 

I don't really care about the format the output will have as long as I don't run one query per letter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd  suggest sub-stringing out the first character:

```
select
substring(word,1,1) as firstChar,
count(id)
from...
group by
substring(word,1,1)
```

That seems easier than 26 individual checks.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to make all those checks, because the alphabet is going to be different, according to the language of the user. :/

Comment: Is it always based on the first letter though?

Comment: I only care about the first letter, yes

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having the results in rows instead of columns this should work:

```
SELECT LEFT(word, 1) aChar, count(id) total
FROM words
WHERE word LIKE '[A-Z]%'
GROUP BY LEFT(word, 1)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbce7/1).

Also, according to your comment:

> I have to make all those checks, because the alphabet is going to be different, according to the language of the user

It makes much more sense to use a regular expression here as you can parameterise the value of the regular expression and add or remove characters without changing the code of the query (only the parameter).

Comment: Does this allow me to get the entire alphabet of any language from the regex? For example can I feed this statement the first and last letters of Russian or Greek alphabet and it will work?

If that is possible, I'll accept this question once I've tested it

Comment: No, you can't do that with any solution. That characters you want to match will always have to be selected by you manually. `A-Z` is just a shortcut for the ASCII sequence from `A` to `Z`. If you need to add special characters you have to add them individually like this `'[A-Z∫√πµ]%'`. Check this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26c48/1) to see a sample.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to separate the `COUNT` operation from the subquery, you can do it inline.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'A%') AS A,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%B') AS B,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%C') AS C
```

Comment: Please, this answer doesn't meet SO guidelines on quality answers. Add some explanations on why this solves the OP problem in order to make it useful for the community and improve its quality.

Comment: I've added some clarification.